# Java EE Servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have just started learning Java EE and recently got stuck to a problem. I am using eclipse Galileo and installed Tomcat 6.0 version. I needed to create a small Hello World servlet program for which I did the following.

1. Created a dynamic web project (firstServlet) and inside Java Resource:src created a package.
2. Under package I created a servlet by name 'HelloServlet' and url pattern as '/hello'.
3. In HelloServlet I just override service method taking HttpServletRequest & HttpServletResponse parameters. Further I did
   `response.getWriter.println("Hello Servlet")` to print message on
   browser.
4. Issue is when I hit the url as `http://localhost:8080/firstServlet/hello`, I am always  getting a 404 error.

I did crosscheck that my Tomcat is using port 8080.

```
type Status report
message /firstProject/hello
description The requested resource (/firstProject/hello) is not available. Please Help.
```

Comment: Is your servlet mapped by `web.xml` or by `@WebServlet`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple issue indicating, that it is not finding the class file for the servlet, in the **path given.**

> 1. Please make sure, you have it mapped in web.xml
> 2. In the web.xml the **servlet<> tag** needs to have the class path in the **servlet-class<>** tag of the servlet.
>      If it is **in some package**? it should be **com.somePackage.hello**
> 3. Also, make sure that it does mentions the package properly, in the hello.java file.

This will solve your issue.